# Path and sys.path different using the same virtual env

Tags: python, windows, python-venv, streamlit

Quite new to `venv`...I have 2 projects.

Project A (autotrader): main modules, has a `venv` that is shared with Project B

Project B (autotraderUI): `streamlit` app that utilizes modules from Project A and uses `venv` from project A

For the project A `venv`, I have a `.pth` file inside `/venv/Lib/site-packages/` which makes the `venv` aware of the path location of Project A.

Now for some reason when I have Project B use the same `venv`, it can't find the modules associated with Project A.

More specifically, when I run `source /venv/Scripts/activate` to start the `venv` and then navigate to the Project B `streamlit` app and do `streamlit run app.py`, it doesn't find the Project A...

Any idea why? I mean Project B is using the `venv` python.exe. Why can't Project B find location of project A?

[image: screenshot]

In the picture above, I can see that it's calling the `venv` python so it's not going to the global python.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Pycharm, I would love to see your interpreter directory paths please for the two projects.

Comment: when i do `sys.path` for project B, i don't see project A directory inside it. my question is why thats the case? i am using the venv of Project A which should know this information.

Comment: What IDE are you using please?

Comment: pycharm, but i run the app on command line

Comment: I don't use CLI. Try running your projects in Pycharm editor, let me see the directory in Pycharm.